# jquery codes explanation

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Is there anyone who can explain me this piece of jquery code? I'm stuck with the variables `current` and `next`. What are they actually retrieving?

```
function rotate() { 

//Get the first image

var current = ($('#images .image.show')?  $('#images .image.show') : $('#images .image:first'));
if ( current.length == 0 ) current = $('#images .image:first');
//Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image

var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('#images .image:first') :current.next()) : $('#images .image:first'));
    //Un-comment the 3 lines below to get the images in random order
    //var sibs = current.siblings();
    //var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sibs.length );
    //var next = $( sibs[ rndNum ] );
    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index

next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
//Hide the current image
current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000).removeClass('show');

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [ternary or conditional operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

These are the equivalent of:

```
if($('#images .image.show')){ 
    var current = $('#images .image.show');
}
else{
    var current = $('#images .image:first');
}
```

and

```
if(current.next().length){
    if(current.next().hasClass('show')){
        var next = $('#images .image:first');
    }
    else{
        var next = current.next();
    }
else{
    var next = $('#images .image:first');
}
```

Comment: I knew these are ternary operators.. But couldn't try to wrap those codes up like this way. :) Thanks a lot

Comment: By the way why do you think the image.show is not spaced? What if they were .image .show ? It doesn't work on the slideshow if they were spaced I've tested.

Comment: `.image.show` is attaching the listener to the node which has both class `image` and `show` and `.image .show` would add the listener to class `show` in the descendant nodes of `.image`, so the space does matters

Comment: On the slideshow there's a line "jQuery("#ajax-loader").delay(3000).fadeOut();" which can't be deleted. If I erase slideshow stops working. Can you please explain what it does?